# How to add PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 for android api 8 (Froyo)

Tags: android, security

i need some help. I am writing app and need to use "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1" algorithm (cannot change server side). but that don't work in android (not supported), but then i create android-maven project in eclipse it works fine on Gingerbread, and newest. but on Froyo don't. i try add security provider which have that algorithm but nothing. i can see it in avaylable list, but can't get instance of it. I event try spoungycastle (recompiled bouncecastle), SunJCE. Maybe you have same proposal how to fix it? o some workaroud?

in this line i get error

```
SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
```

Error:

```
W/System.err( 1225): java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SecretKeyFactory PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 implementation not found:
W/System.err( 1225):    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1100)
W/System.err( 1225):    at org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:112)
W/System.err( 1225):    at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(SecretKeyFactory.java:111)
W/System.err( 1225):    at com.ii.app.AppActivity.onCreate(AppActivity.java:46)
W/System.err( 1225):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
W/System.err( 1225):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
W/System.err( 1225):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
W/System.err( 1225):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
W/System.err( 1225):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
W/System.err( 1225):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/System.err( 1225):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
W/System.err( 1225):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
W/System.err( 1225):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err( 1225):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
W/System.err( 1225):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
W/System.err( 1225):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
W/System.err( 1225):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/System.err( 1225): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
W/System.err( 1225):    at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE$2.run(DashoA13*..)
W/System.err( 1225):    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedImpl(AccessController.java:264)
W/System.err( 1225):    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:84)
W/System.err( 1225):    at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE.c(DashoA13*..)
W/System.err( 1225):    at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE.b(DashoA13*..)
W/System.err( 1225):    at com.sun.crypto.provider.PBKDF2HmacSHA1Factory.<init>(DashoA13*..)
W/System.err( 1225):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
W/System.err( 1225):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
W/System.err( 1225):    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1098)
W/System.err( 1225):    ... 16 more
```

Comment: any luck in this, I also having the same error?

Answer (score 0):

Spongycastle works, but it is not straight forward. You have to do something like this:

```
private static byte[] decryptPBKDF2WithBC(char[] password, byte[] data, byte[] salt, byte[] iv)
  throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException,
  InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {

   PBEParametersGenerator generator = new PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator();
   generator.init(PBEParametersGenerator.PKCS5PasswordToUTF8Bytes(password), salt,CryptographicToolBox.CRYPTO_ITERATIONS);
   KeyParameter params = (KeyParameter)generator.generateDerivedParameters(CryptographicToolBox.KEY_SIZE);

   byte[] endcoded = params.getKey();
   SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(endcoded, "AES");

   Cipher ciph = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

   ciph.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(iv);
   return ciph.doFinal(data);
}
```

Comment: I ended with different solution. Now I connect to other server where i can control which encryption algorithm to use. so now i cannot check you answer. If someone whose step on this problem too, write me what this solution is working i will accept answer.

Comment: I love this answer for making it clear to me how IVs can be used.